# Restrict output using Type Families

Tags: haskell

I've this code for which I'm trying to add a constraint using Haskells Type Families. I want to force the output to always be a flip, is that possible with this code?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies #-}

module TF where

data Even
data Odd

data Coin where
  Up :: Coin
  Down :: Coin

type family Flip n :: *
type instance Flip Even = Odd
type instance Flip Odd = Even

up = Up 
down = Down

flip Up   = Down
flip Down = Up
```

Comment: How `Up/Down` and `Even/Odd` are related? If `Up` is always `Even`, then you can index `Coin` by `Parity` like this: `data Parity = Even | Odd`,
`data Coin :: Parity -> * where Up :: Coin Even; Down :: Coin Odd`. Then `flip :: Coin p -> Coin (Flip p)`.

Comment: @user3237465 Thanks for your help. I tired using your example like this, but it doesn't work. https://gist.github.com/oleander/86c65054264c413aaa5a What I'm I missing?

Comment: @Oleander You are missing `{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}`

Comment: @Oleander You also need to change `Flip` so that the result is of kind `Parity` not `*` and you have recursion in the definition of `Flip` that shouldn't be there. Also, you should consider closed type families. I feel that they're usually easier to think about because they're more restricted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting my comment into an answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

data Parity = Even | Odd

data Coin :: Parity -> * where
    Up   :: Coin Even
    Down :: Coin Odd

type family Flip (p :: Parity) :: Parity where
    Flip Even = Odd
    Flip Odd  = Even

flip :: Coin p -> Coin (Flip p)
flip Up   = Down
flip Down = Up
```